# How to correctly emit an event that takes data from a form to the parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-event-emitter

On a value change in the form in the child component I am trying to send an event to the parent component with the changed data from the form, but it keeps telling me that the

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class ClaimItemBoxesComponent implements OnInit {
 @Output() updatedBoxData = new EventEmitter();
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items.valueChanges.subscribe(this.onBoxFormChage);
 }
 onBoxFormChage(item) {
   this.updatedBoxData.emit(item) // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updatedBoxData')
 }
}
```

If I emit the event inside ngOnInit outside the subscribe, it works like it should, but if inside the subscribe it does not.

Comment: Is this complete code?  Where is the component class definition?

Comment: Just added and edited the question with more details. The whole component is hundreds lines of code, I just posted where the problem occurs.

Comment: You have to use an arrow function instead of passing onBoxFormChage directly. `.subscribe(this.onBoxFormChage)` => `.subscribe(item => this.onBoxFormChage(item))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lost the context here, just bind it, or use lambda function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items.valueChanges.subscribe(this.onBoxFormChage.bind(this));
}
```

or

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => this.onBoxFormChage(value));
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you that works! But why does it loos the context?